# how can create view for like a post similar instagram in MySql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, sql-view

I have 3 tables in my database:

table 1:user_table:
userId | userName | userPass

table 2:posts_table:
postId | postTitle | UserId

table 3:likeTable:
userId | postId

now,how can create view for  like a post similar instagram in MySql query?

I want my output table to look like the following,All posts are displayed and if the users likes it, the number is 1 and otherwise the NULL value

outputTableView:

```
postId | postTitle | likeCount | userLike(forUsers)
----------------------------------------
1        Title1         100         1 (value 1 for like)
2        Title2         200         NULL
3        Title3         150         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
select 
    p.post_id, 
    p.post_title, 
    count(l.post_id) likes_count, 
    nullif(max(l.user_id = ?), 0) user_likes
from posts_table p
left join like_table l on l.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id
```

The question mark should be replaced with the id of the user for which you want to build the report.

Comment: thank's GMB.I want to implement this for my application. How can I do this using View?

Comment: @meisamemadian: view don't take parameters. You can run the query directly from your application, passing the user id as a parameter.